# $23^{54^{26}}\bmod45$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$$23^{54^{26}}\bmod45$$
Any hints? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE kindly tell us your thoughts on this question

Comment: Is it $23$ raised to the power of $54^{26}$, or $23^{54}$ raised to the power of $26$?

Comment: We can use WolframAlpha to tell us that the answer is $1 \mod 45$, whether you mean [$23^{(54^{26})}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=23%5E(54%5E26)+mod+45) or [$(23^{54})^{26}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(23%5E54)%5E26+mod+45)

Comment: Have you heard about the Chinese remainder theorem? Have you heard about Fermat's little theorem and Euler's theorem? If you have, then this problem should be a piece of cake. At the very least you should be able to tell us where you're stuck. If you haven't, you should read up on them, either on the internet or in your book, and then try again.

Comment: Using modular exponentiation, use the fact that $23^{12} \equiv 1 \pmod {45}$, and then show that $54^{26} | 12$.

Comment: Or better yet $12|54^{26}$.  Typing can be an art.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: First observe that

$$23^{54^{26}} = 23^{54^{23}.54^{3}}$$

So consider $23^{{54}^3}$. By Euler's theorem, noting that $\phi(45)=24$, we have
$$23^{24} = 1 \mod 45$$

Now note that $24|54^3$. Can you do the rest?

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$23^{54^m}\equiv23^{54^m\pmod{\lambda(45)}}\pmod{45}$$

Now using [Carmichael Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CarmichaelFunction.html) $\lambda(45)=12$

Now as $6|54, 54^m\equiv0\pmod{12}$ for $m\ge2$

Answer (score 1):

We have $45=5\times 9$ where $5$ and $9$ are relatively prime.  Then with $23$ and $45$ relatively prime, $23^n \equiv 1$ mod $45$ when $n $ is divisible by both $\phi (5)=4$ and $\phi (9)=6$.  As $n=54^{26}=2^{26}\times 3^{78}$ meets this criterion we are sure the remainder will be $1$.